# Is $g$ an injective continuous mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For an artibtrary $t \in \mathbb R $, let's define a mapping 
$$g: (0,1)  \to  R^2$$   as follows: 
$$g(\alpha)=  \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{\alpha}}\cos(t\ln(n)), \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{\alpha}}\sin(t\ln(n))  \right). $$

**Question** Is  $g$ an injective continuous mapping ?

Answer (score 3):

Identify $\Bbb R^2$ with $\Bbb C$. Then $(\cos x,\sin x)$ becomes $\cos x+i\sin x=e^{ix}$ and so
$$ g(\alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^{n+1}}n^{-\alpha+it}$$
Maybe that halps.

Comment: Thank you very much,  but the answer must be  : ''Yes'' or ''No''